# Altering color of individual sprite in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I just started playing around with three.js and I'm having some trouble modifying the color of individual sprites within an array.

I'm working with the example found [here](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_particles_waves), from threejs.org.

I'm attempting to modify each sprite's color based on its scale value. In particular, I added the following line to the last function, from the source file.

```
            function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            var i = 0;

            for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

                for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

                    particle = particles[ i++ ];
                    particle.position.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) * 50 ) +
                        ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) * 50 );
                    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) + 1 ) * 4 +
                        ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 4;

                    // Added this line in an attempt to change color based on scale //
                    particle.material.color.setHSL(particle.scale.x * .1, .2, .2);


                }

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

            count += 0.1;

        }
```

However, the added line changes every particle to the same color values. I'd assumed that each element of the array would be accessed and modified within the loop, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer about each sprite having its own material sent me in the right direction. I set material to an array and added an association between each material and sprite element.

```
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;

            for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

                for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

                    material[ j ] = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

                    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
                    program: function ( context ) {

                        context.beginPath();
                        context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
                        context.fill();

                     }

                    } );

                    particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Sprite( material[ j ++ ] );
                    particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
                    particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
                    scene.add( particle );

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The material is being shared with all the particles,

```
            var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

                color: 0xffffff,
                program: function ( context ) {

                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
                    context.fill();

                }

            } );
```

Move this above the loop where the sprites particles are created so they get a separate material each.